# How do i get alt-text for an image from Google Custom Search API

Tags: javascript, html, image, api

I want to use Google's Custom Search API to get a list of images. How do i get alt-text for each image?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. There is a HTMLsnippet parameter in the response which is what I required.